# Mips questions on stack management, array coding, and overflow insight

Tags: arrays, stack, mips

How do I generate a function which takes elements from two vectors (while configuring stack properly) and passing the operands via stack to a FUNCTION? I defined my vectors in data portion of my code.

I don't know how to take the elements (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) from the their vector and passing the operands via stack? Does anyone have any programming insight on this topic? I know an example of pushing a stack is

```
Sub  sp, sp, 0
Li   s0, 0x12345678
Sw   s0, 0(sp)
```

And an example of popping a stack is

```
Lw  s0, 0(sp)
Add sp, sp, 0
```

The part I'm confused at is implement my array elements while passing onto the stack. We were told specifically not to use registers to pass the parameters. Or else I would just itemize each number into a register and try and pass them that way. This is the second time that I am taking the class. I have the textbook. I have seen mips run. I have watched tutorials on mips via youtube. (#sys call is a term for just do it. #mad props to that guy) I guess what I am trying to say is that any helpful input would be appreciated.

I rewrote my code so its more readable for others.

```
.globl main  #tells assembler that there is a global routine called main

.data

array1: .word 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, -12 #define array 1(6x1 vector)
array2: .word -1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 #define array 2(6x1 vector)

.text

main: # I am trying to configure the stack properly and pass parameters 
      # (vector elements) to dot_product function

 addiu $sp, $sp, -32 # Allocating space on the stack.
                     # I need to pass two operands via stack onto num mult
                     # and multiply them together

 sw $t1, array1+0x00($sp) #placing first element of array at Mem[Sp]
 sw $t2, array1+0x04($sp) #placing second element of array at Mem[Sp+4]
 sw $t3, array1+0x08($sp) #placing third element of array at Mem[Sp+8]
 sw $t4, array1+0x0C($sp) #placing fourth element of array at Mem[Sp+12]
 sw $t5, array1+0x10($sp) #placing fifth element of array at Mem[Sp+16]
 sw $t6, array1+0x04($sp) #placing sixth element of array at Mem[Sp+20]
 sw $ra, 24($sp)          #saving return address

                          #Should I have an equivalent amount of lw so I
                          #de-allocate space on the stack? If so, then what
                          #is the purpose of allocating space on the stack
                          # in the first place. I don't see the point.

 nop

 jal num_mult #Call num_mult Function. I don't know why this is here. I just
              # placed so others knew that I was inept at programming. 
 nop

 dot_product: # takes elements from each vector and after configuring stack
              # appropriately passes two operands via stack to num_mult
              # calculate sum of RETURNED values from each call to num_mult

 addi $t7, $v0, $v1 # $v0 and $v1 are return values from a function call
                    # This is my running sum calculator
 mov $v0, $t7       # This returns the sum in $v0 
 addi $v1, $zero, 0 # Places 0 in $v1

 bgt $t0, 32767, else # dot_product tests checks for overflow

  addi $v0, $zero, 0  #if overflow, then dot_product will return zero in $v0
  addi $v1, $zero, -1 #reg and -1 in $v1 reg

  else:        
     addi $v0, 0, $t0 # if no overflow then dot_product will return product 
     addi $v1, 0, -1  # in $v0 reg and zero in $v1 reg

     #dot_product should check for overflow in running sum calculation
     #process. If overflow in running sum, dot_product should return zero
     #too.

  num_mult: 

  mult $a0, $a1  # takes two operands passed via stack and multiplies them
                 # together
  mflo $t0
  bgt $t0, 32767, else1 # num_mult tests result to determine if product can
                        # be accurately represented in 32 bits

    addi $v0, $zero, 0  # if overflow, then num_mult will return zero in $v0
    addi $v1, $zero, -1 # reg and -1 in $v1 reg

  else1:
     addi $v0, 0, $t0 # if no overflow then num_mult will return product in
     addi $v1, 0, -1  # $v0 reg and zero in $v1 reg

 end:
   nop

   b end #teacher asked for a 'spin' loop but this is all I have. 

   nop
```

The biggest problem that I have is understanding:  taking elements from each vector and after configuring stack appropriately passes two operands via stack to num_mult & calculating sum of RETURNED values from each call to num_mult.

I will through it in the compiler tomorrow. I figure that I hang my dirty laundry up so others could eagerly make their comments. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you pass an array by pushing each element on the stack? That makes no sense. Just pass the address of the array and its length using two registers (e.g. `$a0` and `$a1`).

Comment: That's what the teacher wants. I will ask for clarification today.

Comment: In any case, you want `sw $t1,0x00($sp)`. If `array1` had an address  [under `mars`] of `0x10010000` then `sw $t1,array1+0x00($sp)` would be `sw $t1,0x10010000($sp)`. Also, in your first example for "push", it should be `0($sp)` and similar for the "pop". Try to get clarification from your teacher and edit your question about the problem statement. Usual is `la $a0,array1`, `la $a1,array2`, `li $a3,6`, `jal ...` but these could be pushed, _not_ by value as your 3rd code does, but: `la $t0,array1`, `sw $t0,0($sp)`, `la $t0,array2`, `sw $t0,4($sp)`, `li $t0,6`, `sw $t0,8($sp)`